# ¿Por qué XMLHttpRequest no envía datos?

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando enviar un string a un archivo creado con [table2csv](https://github.com/OmbraDiFenice/table2csv/)

```javascript
var data = $("#tablaCGRAL1").table2csv('return');
var url = "recs/table.txt";
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open("POST", url, true);
http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        console.log(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(data);
```

Un ejemplo del string generado es éste:

```
3619|24|52010|2022-11-07|2022-11-18|52010|800|PRUEBA 1|PRUEBA 2
1|8|PZA|1.00|DISCO DURO SEAGATE 500 GB SATA 2.5 PARA LAPTOP
```

Un `console.log(data)` regresa el string perfectamente bien y completo, y no me marca ningún error en ningún lado, pero por alguna razón el archivo *table.txt* permanece vacío. ¿Cuál podría ser la razón? Ya intenté todo y no cambia nada.

Comment: ¿ Estás intentando directamente desde JavaScript modificar un archivo remoto (que está en el servidor) ?

Comment: Sí. Si se puede hacer de otra forma, tomaré cualquier alternativa.

Comment: No se puede hacer lo que estás diciendo. Debes enviarlo a tu backend y este escribir el csv

Comment: Ok, ¿Cómo? Eso fue lo que intenté primero antes de usar Table2Csv, usé SELECT INTO OUTFILE y no se crea nada porque el usuario no tiene el global privilege FILE y no se lo puedo dar. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo sin usar esa query?

Comment: Puedes crear / modificar el archivo directamente en el servidor, de hecho, es mejor eso y más seguro, que gestionar el archivo por medio de la base de datos. [Lee sobre cómo crear / modificar archivos en PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ref.filesystem.php) (supongo que el servidor trabaja con PHP, si es otro lenguaje de programación, lee cómo trabajar con archivos en ese lenguaje de programación que usarás en el contexto del servidor).

Answer (score 1):

Lo solucioné después de leer sobre modificar archivos en PHP:

```
$open = fopen('C:/wamp64/www/recs/table.txt','w+');
fwrite($open, $TABLAREC);
fclose($open);
```

$TABLAREC es lo que estaba en el data. La envié con ajax a php.